# What executes on 'npm test' when script doesn't specified?

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

In my project there is no script for test, there is no also Jest or mocha, but result of `npm run test` is

```
> myproject@0.1.0 test /path/to/project
> echo 'Error: no test specified'

Error: no test specified
```

and return code 0, but for logic it should be code 1.

I know about config flag `ignore-scripts` with `false` value, but as I understood its about pre- and post- scripts. Also I read about Jest that is npm 'smart' and can detected, but as wrote previous there is no jest package.

```
npm -v
6.14.13
node -v
v12.22.3
```

Does it only for npm v6 and is this fixed in v7 that returns code 1?

Please explain this or give some links because I couldn't find any helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behaviour changed in npm@7, now it occurs an error

https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/CHANGELOG.md#npm-test